# Angular2: Prevent authenticated users from accessing specific routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've defined some `routes` in my `main.ts` file:

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', terminal: true },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent } 
];
```

After successful login I want my authenticated users can be able to use specific routes (e.g. `dashboard`). And without login they cannot access `dashboard` but they can be able to visit **about,home,login**

I've managed to restrict users traversing the `dashboard` without login, using `CanActivate`.

```
canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true; 
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    return false;
  }
```

But Using those routes and the `CanActivate` approach after successful login, users are also able to goto routes like `login`, `home`. How can I prevent that?

N.B. I'm using angular2 RC4.

Comment: Make another CanActivate for login and home that prevents logged in users to access.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I made some researches to see if it's possible to "negate" a guard but seems like you have to make another guard which is the opposite of your guard. Like :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './your-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class PreventLoggedInAccess implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate() {
    return !this.authService.isLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Add it in your bootstrap function as well and you are all set. You just have to do in your routes :

```
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [PreventLoggedInAccess] },
```

Comment: For the answer +1. I thought about this approach. But is this the only solution?

Comment: I dont know... That's how I would do it. If you find a more elegant solution let me know.

Comment: I wish you could just negate it like this `canActivate: [!LoggedInGuard]`.

Answer (score 6):

Make ts file name auth.guard.ts put following code on that

Write guard code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }
        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add bellow code in your routing ts file

app-routing.module.ts

```
{
      path: 'user', component: UserComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard] ,
      children: [{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
                 { path: 'view/:id', component: UserViewComponent },
                 { path: 'add', component: UserAddComponent },
                 { path: 'edit/:id', component: UserAddComponent }
                ]  
  },
```

Add providers in your app.module.ts file

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    --------
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    --------
  ],
  providers: [      
    AuthGuard        
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You could write a guard like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    CanActivate,
    RouterStateSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './your-auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserAccessGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return route.data['onlyGuests'] != authService.isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

And then use it in your route definition:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home' },

  // accessible only to guests
  {
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent,
      data: { onlyGuests: true },
      canActivate: [ UserAccessGuard ]
  },
  {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent,
      data: { onlyGuests: true },
      canActivate: [ UserAccessGuard ]
  },

  // accessible only to authenticated users
  {
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent,
      canActivate: [ UserAccessGuard ]
  }
];
```