# How to prevent navigation to login and registration url after login in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I am tying to prevent users from navigating to login and registration url by manually typing the url in the address bar after successful login or registration. I implemented Auth Guard for other urls which user cannot access without logging in. Here is my Auth Guard implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!this.userService.getLoggedInStatus()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

And I am using it in my app.route.ts like this:

```
{ path:'checkout', component:CheckoutComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard] }
```

How can I achieve the reverse for login and register component i.e. only activate them if user is not logged in and deactivate once user logs in?

Comment: This seems ilke something that has been asked many times before. Literally the second link in google search... Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915893/angular2-prevent-authenticated-users-from-accessing-specific-routes

Comment: @Baruch I was able to solve it by following the link you provided. Thanks!